# Firefox and a very simple flexbox layout failing

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

We have a `button` with `display:flex` that contains statically positioned inline elements.
There is no absolute positioning involved, basically nothing special, and as can be seen even in the simplified fiddle, Firefox displays the children top-to-bottom instead of left-to-right.

https://jsfiddle.net/loopmode/4fzyhb2f/2/

I must be missing something almost trivial...?

Of course I could just remove `display:flex` and render everything inline, then it looks ok in FF for this simple case.
However, elsewhere I need to use other flex features like `flex-direction` so `display: inline` is not a viable workaround.